# How to query a string column with a list of keywords with sqlalchemy orm and core?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

```py
class Message(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'message'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = Column(Text)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<{self.__class__.__name__}({self.id}, {self.content})>'
```

`message.content` is sentence record, i.e. long string. How may I query the record that contains any elements in a list of keywords?

for example, Suppose the `msg` records and the list of `keywords` are the following:

```
'Chris likes Tea and orange', 'Bob likes Coffee and apple', 'Alice likes Tea too'
keywords = ['Tea', 'orange']
```

then it returns

```
['Chris likes Tea and orange', 'Alice likes Tea too']
```

what is the correct way to do this query in SQLalchemy ORM and core?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @IljaEverilä SQLite

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to form an EXISTS subquery expression that tests against the list of keywords:

```py
import json

from sqlalchemy import column, exists, func, select

# json_each is a TVF, table valued function
kws = func.json_each(json.dumps(keywords)).alias()
kws = select([column("value")]).select_from(kws).cte()

session.query(Message).\
    filter(exists().
           where(Message.content.contains(kws.c.value)).
           correlate(Message))
```

If you need to search over a large table, you might be interested in FTS5. Integrating it with SQLAlchemy is not quite straightforward, but [doable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893974/how-to-use-sqlalchemy-to-create-a-full-text-search-index-on-sqlite-and-query-it).