# SQLAlchemy SQLite FTS MATCH on entire index, not just a single column

Tags: sqlalchemy, full-text-search

[SQLite FTS 5](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html) allows matching on the entire index:

```sql
SELECT product_name, description, retail_price
FROM auctionlot_idx
WHERE auctionlot_idx MATCH 'mx AND master AND dongel'
```

This will match documents that have mx & master and dongel in the FTS index. I am trying to use integrate this functionality with SQLAlchemy, [following this excellent answer as a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893974/how-to-use-sqlalchemy-to-create-a-full-text-search-index-on-sqlite-and-query-it/49917886#49917886). Near the end of the answer, it demonstrates how to use the MATCH operator:

```py
        stmt = select(AuctionLotIdx).where(AuctionLotIdx.product_name.op("MATCH")("mx master"))
```

I was wondering what the best way to generate a query like the one above while staying as much as possible in the SQLAlchemy way of doing things.

The following is what I thought could be a workaround, but is not equivalent, for example one of the terms may appear only in one column:

```sql
SELECT product_name, description, retail_price
FROM auctionlot_idx
WHERE auctionlot_idx.product_name MATCH 'mx AND master AND dongel'
  OR auctionlot_idx.description MATCH 'mx AND master AND dongel'
  OR auctionlot_idx.title MATCH 'mx AND master AND dongel'
```

Since none of the columns match the entire condition on their own, this query won't work.

Comment: `select(AuctionLotIdx).where(column("auctionlot_idx").op("MATCH")("mx AND master AND dongel"))` you can import `column` as `from sqlalchemy import column`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @python_user and [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893974/how-to-use-sqlalchemy-to-create-a-full-text-search-index-on-sqlite-and-query-it/49917886#comment-125672253) of the very answer I linked, the way to do this is with `column` and the way I used it as follows:

```py
def fts_column_MATCH(table: Table) -> Callable[[Any], BinaryExpression[Any]]:
    return column(table.__tablename__).op("MATCH")

# later
stmt = select(AuctionLotIdx).where(fts_column_MATCH(AuctionLotIdx)("some FTS query"))
```

Maybe there's a more SQLAlchem-ic way to write this to be more consistent with the style, but this works for me.